# I am trying to show image preview in listview of images dynamically but I get null bitmap every time

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to show image preview in listview of images dynamically but i get null bitmap every time.

```
File f1 = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIP/myImage.jpg");
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());
 /* here bitMap becomes null */
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fixed SDCard url, its not same in every Android devices.

For e.g.

```
/mnt/sdcard/
/sdcard
```

Instead use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

For example:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```